# Flutter App can't run on IoS simulator with cycle inside runner, and domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain, code=63

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter, flutter-dependencies

I am having problems since the IoS 14 update. At first it was the deployment target 8.0 and it could temporalily fixed by updating GoogleInfoPlist every time I pulled from our repo in Git. but after a while this temporary fix doesn't work anymore. I got header problem for my FlutterFire plugins.

> warning: double-quoted include "FLTFirebaseCorePlugin.h" in framework header, expected angle-bracketed instead [-Wquoted-include-in-framework-header]
> #import "FLTFirebaseCorePlugin.h"
> ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
> <firebase_core/FLTFirebaseCorePlugin.h>

I have updated my deprecated Firebase core,auth and firestore plugin to the newest one with the help of the flutterfire migration guide. after that the firebase plugin problem was fixed. but i still got problems with 2 plugins: Google Maps Flutter and Image Picker. Waht i did to fix the problem was updating Cocoapods to the beta version for the Google Maps plugin but ther was still a problem with the image picker for the moment i deleted the plugin form my app.

After that i got 3 errors. the first one is the CodeSign cycle inside Runner Error :

> error: Cycle inside Runner; building could produce unreliable results.Target 'Runner': CodeSign /Users/user/StudioProjects/app/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/Runner.app
> ○ Target 'Runner' has copy command from '/Users/vaisatriani/StudioProjects/kuliner_11_app/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/Runner.app' to

I searched for a fix and i found that flutter clean can fix that error. The error did go away but one new error popped out :

> error: '/Users/Username/StudioProjects/appname/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/GoogleService-Info.plist' is longer than filepath buffer size (1025). (in target 'Runner' from project 'Runner')

And i somehow fixed it by removing Runner as Target from Product in XCode. but now i'm stuck with this one error.

> Unable to install /Users/user/StudioProjects/app/build/ios/iphonesimulator/Runner.app on FFF556AF-19DB-4B7B-93BF-A67EE0EA8621. This is sometimes caused by a malformed plist file:
> ProcessException: Process exited abnormally:
> An error was encountered processing the command (domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain, code=63):
> copyfile of file:///Users/user/StudioProjects/app/build/ios/iphonesimulator/Runner.app/ to file:///Users/user/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/FFF556AF-19DB-4B7B-93BF-A67EE0EA8621/data/Containers/Shared/SystemGroup/systemgroup.com.apple.installcoordinationd/Library/InstallCoordination/PromiseStaging/EF2DB4B2-5512-4C14-BCA3-FA7667170000/Runner.app failed: File name too long
> Unhandled error domain NSPOSIXErrorDomain, code 63
> Command: /usr/bin/xcrun simctl install FFF556AF-19DB-4B7B-93BF-A67EE0EA8621 /Users/user/StudioProjects/app/build/ios/iphonesimulator/Runner.app

I couldn't fix it by deleting Derived Data. Does somebody knows how to fix this?? i'm stuck with this problem for a while now. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 5):

Found a fix for this error. what i did was to reset the simulator (Device -> Erase All Content and Settings), and then run $ flutter clean after that rebuild your app.

Answer (score 2):

- delete → Runner.xcworkspace → xcuserdata folder
- delete → Pods folder on inside ios folder
- delete → ios → flutter → Flutter.podspec
- run flutter clean
- flutter run